# trying to get AWS Transcribe output into readable format

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-transcribe

I'm trying to use [t.scribe](https://github.com/kibaffo33/aws_transcribe_to_docx/blob/master/README.md) to transcribe an AWS transcription.

```
pip install tscribe
Successfully installed
aws-transcribe-transcript-master istrauss$ tscribe.write("gabi.json", format="docx")
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"gabi.json",'
```

I copied the format in the doc exactly (just changed the file name to my file) so I don't know what the syntax error could be.

This is my third attempt to convert my json transcription into something more readable. I'm just looking for a simple way to do this — it's just for me to view my own transcript locally, and there's only one speaker.

Comment: Did you get the change to look at the AWS CLI commands provided for AWS Transcribe service? Link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/transcribe/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[tscribe · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/tscribe/) is a **Python library**. You would need to call it from a Python script:

```py
import tscribe

tscribe.write("gabi.json", format="docx")
```

The output you show in your question is running it in the bash command line, not as Python.

Alternatively, you can use:

- The official [AWS Python SDK for Amazon Transcribe](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/transcribe.html), *or*
- The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI) commands for Amazon Transcribe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/transcribe/index.html).